# performance issue with my application

Tags: android, fragment, view

I noticed for a while that I am having an issue loading a specific fragment.
I assumed that is something with the logic`s of the fragment, but when I deleted all the logic in onCreateView function of the fragment, I left only the views and then run over the application, I noticed that the loading time remains the same, then I tried to measure the time to load the fragment, but unfortunately it is always takes ~500-600 ms (I started to calculate the time in onclick function before the replace fragment functionality takes place up to the point of onResume in the problematic fragment) but in real device it`s take ~3 seconds, then I tried to use hierarchyviewer in sdk tools to check the hierarchy of the views. I found out that I have 280 views and the max depth is 15.
My only device is Samsung Tab 3 10.1 (The application will run only on that device)

Comment: Well thanks for letting us know. Do you have a question?

Comment: The question is very simple why the layout loads after ~3 seconds, even if printed the times as I said before it takes 400 MS. do I exceeded the views amount in single layout or depth of view hierarchy?

Comment: What exactly are you measuring at 400 (or is it 500-600?) milliseconds?  I didn't quite get that part, but I'm thinking it's a red herring anyway.  It would seem that if all you're doing is loading views, and it takes 3 seconds, then it's because of your views.  280 views is a lot, and the more views it has to render, and the more complex the layout, the longer it will take.

Comment: I am attempting to measure the loading time of the fragment, I print a log when I am pressing the button to enter the fragment and print another log when I am in the onResume on this fragment, the difference between the two times is about 500 millis but It feels like it loading in about 2-3 seconds

Comment: For more precise information, you can use the profiler in DDMS.  That will tell you exactly where the app is spending its time, including all the system methods that lay out the screen. https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html